# How to enable index.php file in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

We used the CodeIgniter framework to build our site. Currently, it seems someone hack on and set the index.html as default.

Can anyone tell how to set index.php as default?

Please review the site at http://www.nghenghiepviet.com. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Regards,
Dung Nguyen

Answer (score 1):

**You're advertising don't you ?**

and CodeIgniter is built by Experts not by you, so they can think better than you. no chance some one can hack in codeigniter. it's a **Big Deal**

Comment: Hi. I am not advertising for the site. Currently, when visit the home page I get the message like "DOMAIN FOR SALE.....". I currently do not have any developer in hand to help so that is why I post in here. Please give any suggestion.

Comment: If your code is on EC2 server then connect to it. then change it back to what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Goto `config/config.php`, Change this

```
$config[base_url] = "http://www.nghenghiepviet.com/index.php";
```

Comment: It would be great to include a short explanation with this answer!